# Will Ubuntu.com and Askubuntu.com be available in other languages?

Tags: discussion

Simple question: Why is the information on Ubuntu.com and Askubuntu.com only available in English? Will the official sites ever get translated into other languages, in order to make it more accessible internationally?

Thanks.

Comment: This depends, at least on the askubuntu site on how the developers of the stackexchange network add the code needed for multi language support. In my case and with others that also speak my language (spanish) we try our best to help any spanish speaking user. The same goes for other members that help with other languages.

Comment: I've helped Polish, Brazilians, Frenchs, I think that a Greek, and several in spanish before D:

Comment: Ubuntu.com is just in English becase there are LoCo websites. See e.g. the website of the Italian LoCo Team: http://ubuntu-it.org

Answer (score 6):

We can't really answer the question of Ubuntu.com seeing as that is run by a totally different set of people (Canonical). Whether or not this site gets support for other languages is solely up to the parent company, Stack Exchange, and only likely to happen if the entire platform gets multi-language support.

In any case, the main hurdle will be having enough people to support the site in *their* language. If both of these criteria are fulfilled (S.E. implementing the support and us having enough active community members to make it work), then there would be nothing stopping it :)

Comment: There is [StackOverflow in Arabic](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58628/stackoverflow-in-arabic?referrer=Ec_DZP20ZOn3kIuW__R2Mw2) already!

Answer (score 4):

About Ask Ubuntu , there is already a blueprint **pending approval** for the translation - localization in other languages. [See here.](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/community-1305-q+a-systems-localization). 
So be patient and eventually the project will be approved and the localization will begin. I participate there for the translation in my native language (GR), you can participate too. You need a Launchpad account to click the `subscribe` button and from that time you will be informed via e-mail of any change to the project.

About Ubuntu.com site, I've found [this project](https://launchpad.net/website-localization), but it seems frozen. You can open a bug in Launchpad against this, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are seperate sites for other languages. For example, for Dutch:

http://www.ubuntu-nl.org

http://vraag.ubuntu-nl.org